# python : wget module downloading file without any extension

Tags: python, http-headers, python-3.6, wget, urllib

I am writing small python code to download a file from follow link and retrieve original filename 
and its extension.But I have come across one such follow link for which python downloads the file but it is without any extension whereas file has .txt extension when downloads using browser.

Below is the code I am trying :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import unquote
import wget

filePath = 'D:\\folder_path'
followLink = 'http://example.com/Reports/Download/c4feb46c-8758-4266-bec6-12358'
response = urlopen(followLink)
if response.code == 200:
    print('Follow Link(response url) :' + response.url)
    print('\n')
    unquote_url = unquote(response.url)
    file_name = wget.detect_filename(response.url).replace('|', '_')
    print('file_name - '+file_name)
    wget.download(response.url,filePa
```

th)

file_name variable in above code is just giving 'c4feb46c-8758-4266-bec6-12358' as filename.
Where I want to download it as c4feb46c-8758-4266-bec6-12358.txt.

I have also tried to read file name from header  i.e. response.info(). But not getting proper file name.

Anyone can please help me with this.I am stucked in my work.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wget gets the filename from the URL itself. For example, if your URL was `https://someurl.com/filename.pdf`, it is saved as `filename.pdf`. If it was `https://someurl.com/filename`, it is saved as `filename`. Since `wget.download` returns the filename of the downloaded file, you can rename it to any extension you want with `os.rename(filename, filename+'.<extension>')`.

Comment: Yes but I cannot rename it since I need to process the files further based on their extension.

Comment: Are all the files of the same extension?

Comment: Since you are using `urlopen` to check if the url is valid, you can use the same response to get the file (in should be in the response body which you can get by `response.read()`) and save it with any name you want. If you want to stick with wget, once the download is done and even before you start processing, rename it.

Comment: thank you...files can be of different extension everytime.we are receiving this files download links.

Comment: Filename doesn't matter as long as I am getting right contents in downloaded file.Matter is I am getting file without any extension.Can you please help me? Wget.detect-filename was working fine but for this case it's not working.

Comment: File extensions never matter. Extensions are something the OS or some tools use to identify what type of file it is. Irrespective of the extensions, the contents of the file will always be the same.

Comment: Yeah..but I am using the file extension to differentiate the files and to decide what action to be taken in future according to its type.Is there any consistent way by which I can get exact filename that gets download using follow link?